# Permission Denied while viewing a PDF file in a react-native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-pdf

This is my react native code for a button, which shows a list of all pdfs and on select, I want to open the pdf withing the app. I am using Document Picker, react-native-pdf. I have been trying so many options but either get an actiond_document_viewer error or this storage permissions issue

Android 13 - I know that they have changed the permissions for images/ videos however for the doucments like PDF, i dont think the permissions are required

```
const App = (): React.ReactElement => {
  const [filePath, setFilePath] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const STORAGE_KEY = '@savedFilePath';

  const requestStoragePermission = async () => {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        {
          title: 'Storage Permission Required',
          message: 'This app requires access to your storage to open files.',
          buttonPositive: 'OK',
        }
      );
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        console.log('Storage permission granted');
        return true;
      } else {
        console.log('Storage permission denied');
        return false;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error requesting storage permission:', error);
      return false;
    }
  };

  const pickFile = async () => {
    try {
      const permissionGranted = await requestStoragePermission();
      if (!permissionGranted) {
        console.log('Storage permission not granted');
        return;
      }
      
      // Proceed to pick the file
      const res: DocumentPickerResponse[] | DocumentPickerResponse | null = await DocumentPicker.pick({
        type: [DocumentPicker.types.pdf],
        copyTo: 'documentDirectory', // Copy the selected file to the app's document directory
      });
      if (res) {
        if (Array.isArray(res)) {
          const selectedFile = res[0];
          const fileCopyUri = `file://${decodeURIComponent(selectedFile.uri)}`;
          setFilePath(fileCopyUri);
          await AsyncStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, fileCopyUri);
        } else {
          const selectedFile = res as DocumentPickerResponse;
          const fileCopyUri = `file://${decodeURIComponent(selectedFile.uri)}`;
          setFilePath(fileCopyUri);
          await AsyncStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, fileCopyUri);
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error picking file:', error);
    }
  };
  

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(filePath);
  }, [filePath]);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={[styles.container]}>
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <Button title="Pick a File" onPress={pickFile} />
      </View>
      {filePath && (
        <View style={styles.pdfContainer}>
          <Pdf source={{ uri: filePath }} style={styles.pdf} />
        </View>
      )}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

My permissions are in Android Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

What is decodeURIComponent used for?
You should retrieve the pdf uri like this.

```
const fileCopyUri = selectedFile.fileCopyUri;
```

Please check out copyTo parameter detail.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-document-picker#ios-and-android-only-copytocachesdirectory--documentdirectory